# my isStopWord function thinks "cat" and "catnip" are the same words

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write a simple function that takes in a word and a stopword to see if they are the same words. It will return true if they are.
So far, by doing this,

```
function isStopWord(word, stopWords) {
  return (stopWords.indexOf(word) !== -1);
}

console.log(isStopWord("cat", "cat"));
```

returns true, but doing this

```
console.log(isStopWord("cat", "catnip");
```

Also returns true... Now, I don't think I know well enough as to how ".indexOf" works to figure out why it returns true in both cases. Can anyone help me fix this function so that it knows if it's the same word and not just from the first three letters? Because doing this,

```
console.log(isStopWord("catnip", "cat");
```

returns false, so i'm a little bit confused. 
Thanks!

Comment: Pass an _array of words_ as the second argument.

Comment: `indexOf` gets the index of where the matching word begins. The word "catnip" begins with "cat", so the index will be 0. The word "cat" does not contain "catnip" at all, so the index will return as -1.

Comment: `indexOf` does a strict compare. it knows nothing about words.

Comment: You could just check word == stopword.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`String.prototype.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) method returns the position of the first occurrence of a specified value in a string. Thus `cat` has one occurence inside `catnip` thus the `index` returned will be `!== 1`

If you just want to check one word to another one. Use the following snippet.

```js
function isStopWord(word, stopWords) {
  return stopWords === word;
}

console.log(isStopWord("cat", "cat"));
console.log(isStopWord("catnip", "cat"));
```

If you want to see if a word is present inside an array of words, use the following snipper which is using [`Array.prototype.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

```js
function isStopWord(word, stopWords) {
  return stopWords.indexOf(word) !== -1;
}

console.log(isStopWord("cat", ["cat", "dog", "bird"]));
console.log(isStopWord("catnip", ["cat", "dog", "bird"]));
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the clarification! I've been using indexOf() to compare words the entire time.

Comment: @yunjae123 You were wrong this entire time hehe. You can still use to find if a string is part of another string